# Execute Jar from Java code

Tags: java, jar

I have this code that is supposed to run a executable jar, but whenever the code is executed nothing happens?

```
      try {
           proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar C://X-Dock//MP3Player.jar");
      } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
      }
```

The JAR works fine if I run it manually, but that line of code just doesn't work. And I know for sure that the code is called.

Comment: try `ProcessBuilder` instead

Comment: Also you don't need to "double" forward-slashes in a string, only backslashes.

Comment: Have you tried running the jar from CMD or by creating .bat file?

Comment: @OndrejTokar Making it target a bat instead of a jar worked. Not sure why, but thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but I have faced very similar problem. The issue might be path to the file. Maybe you could also try placing the jar locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you has a JRE after version 5, java provides a process builder. So, try something like this:

```
final ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/java/path", "-jar", "your_jar.jar");
pBuilder.directory(new File("your/working/directory"));
final Process process = pBuilder.start();
```

"/java/path" is path for java installation, can be replaced by java, if java is in the environment variables.

See more at [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).